# Runtime error of boost asynchronous I/O example

Tags: windows, debugging, visual-c++, runtime, boost-asio

Recently I need to work with boost TCP iostream so I've been trying to compile the daytime [server](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/iostreams/daytime_server.cpp) and [client](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/iostreams/daytime_client.cpp) in iostream [example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html) of boost (v1.50.0) asynchronous I/O with both g++ 4.6 on Ubuntu 12.04 and MSVC 11.0 (Visual Studio 2012 RC) on Windows 7. The program compiles and runs as expected on Linux. From that can we infer that source code of boost example is completely correct so I don't past here for short. Besides, all MSVC project settings and link to boost binaries are OK since it compiles fine with only warning C4250 that [according to Microsoft](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/733720/inheriting-from-std-fstream-produces-c4250-warning) is alright.

The problem is that both server and client crash at runtime on Windows and the error looks something like `0x000007FEEE9082DE (msvcp110d.dll) (***.exe) unhandled exception: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (arguement: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00000000000C3FF0)` in debug.

When I left server running background and was debugging client, a stack trace
[image]
showed the calling stack. I digged in the source of ostream and found that in the constructor of `sentry` in `basic_ostream`

```
explicit __CLR_OR_THIS_CALL sentry(_Myt& _Ostr)
        : _Sentry_base(_Ostr)
        {   // construct locking and testing stream
        if (_Ostr.good() && _Ostr.tie() != 0)
            _Ostr.tie()->flush();
        _Ok = _Ostr.good(); // store test only after flushing tie
        }
```

is there a call `_Ostr.tie()->flush()` and in definition of `flush()`

```
_Myt& __CLR_OR_THIS_CALL flush()
    {   // flush output stream
    if (_Myios::rdbuf() != 0)
        {   // buffer exists, flush it
        const sentry _Ok(*this);

        if (_Ok && _Myios::rdbuf()->pubsync() == -1)
            _Myios::setstate(ios_base::badbit); // sync failed
        }
    return (*this);
    }
```

constructs a constant sentry `_Ok`. I assume this is a bug but I'm not sure about it.

So my questions are that is this a bug of runtime of MSVC 11.0 in your opinion? Does server or client, if compiling with MSVC 10.0 (Visual Studio 2010), crash on your Windows system for the same reason?

Comment: This issue is reported and under review at connect. You can follow the issue [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/772293).